# opencv cascade haartraining bad result

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I have 616 positive image profile face and 3020 image negative and I use this code to make my vector sample:

```
createsamples.exe -info positive/info.txt -vec vector/facevector.vec -num 616 -w 24 -h 24
```

> size of vector 694 KB
>
> size of image 630 * 480

and I use this for haartraining:

```
haartraining.exe -data cascades -vec vector/facevector.vec -bg negative/bg.txt -npos 616 -nneg 3020 -nstages 19 -nsplits 2 -nonsym -minhitrate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -mem 1024 -mode ALL -w 24 -h 24 PAUSE
```

and when it finishes I change it to cascade by:

```
haarconv.exe data myfacedetector.xml 24 24
```

and I have only 56 cascade size also my training data size all (every stage) its 1 KB or 2KB. When I test it it dosen't detect any face also the training positive image is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, in `haartraining.exe` command `-npos` is not the number of poisitive images you have; it is the number little less than the number of samples (say `0.9*(number of samples)`).

Second thing, I don't see how many samples you are creating using `createsamples.exe` command. Again, you don't specify number of positive images here; you should specify how many samples you want to create using those positive images you have. Please study the parameters again. 
Hope this helps!